# Does AWS charge for replication if master and slave are in different availability zones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cost-explorer

My DB master instance is in ap-south-1a and my slave instances are in ap-south-1b. Does this contribute to higher replication cost or will it be the same since the region is same?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Cost is higher if the regions are different. Different availability zones will not incur additional cost